# How can I use Github Copilot in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, github-copilot

Is it possible to use the new [Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot) plugin from GitHub in Android Studio? I see they advertise it for Visual Code, but I am working in Android Studio and I would like to test it.

GitHub (https://github.com/features/copilot?utm_medium=email&utm_source=announcement&utm_campaign=copilot-technical-preview)
GitHub Copilot · Your AI pair programmer
GitHub Copilot works alongside you directly in your editor, suggesting whole lines or entire functions for you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

UPDATE: As Chiara mentioned, now its just as easy as go to: File → Settings → Plugins and just search for "GitHub Copilot".

---

Deprecated:

Yes it is, You need to go to the JetBrains [marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17718-github-copilot/versions), download the latest Copilot plugin version and then manually install it in Android Studio.
See pictures attached.
Go to settings [image: settings] then go to manual plugin installation [image: manual plugin installation] then go to install from disk [image: install from disk] and then choose plugin location (choose the one you downloaded in the first step).[image: plugin location]

Comment: Copilot comes up in the Marketplace search now under File → Settings → Plugins and no longer needs to be manually installed. I confirmed that it has the latest version.

Answer (score 60):

File --> Settings --> Plugins --> type "copilot" in search field and install.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac & Android Studio Dolphin:

[image]