# How do I get Github Copilot to work in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, github-copilot

I bought the monthly subscription and installed the plugin in the latest version of android studio flamingo. But when I type, no suggestions pop up. I tested it in vscode for javascript and it's working fine there, just not in android studio. I'm using Kotlin at the moment, which from my understanding should still work.

I couldn't find anything helpful in the answers in this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72911525/how-can-i-use-github-copilot-in-android-studio). What else can I try. Would really love to start using github copilot in android studio kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

figured out what wasn't working. Had to login to Github in Android Studio via the tiny Github Copilot icon at the bottom right corner of the IDE.